# ¿Como quitar redirección de IP a una URL de dominio?

Tags: ubuntu, aws, lamp

Tengo una IP canonizada, es decir, mi nombre de dominio y dirección IP se resuelven en la misma URL, y cada que intento ingresar por IP me redirecciona a mi dominio, quisiera quitar esta acción, probé revisando el archivo `httpd.conf` para verificar si tenia las reglas de reescritura pero no las tiene, también revise la configuración del vhost y no tiene ningún alias o redirección de IP. revise en mi directorio raíz si había un `htaccess` con algunas reglas de reescritura y no lo hay, podrían ayudarme por favor.

Comment: Cuándo dices "se resuelven", qué quieres decir. Obviamente no hablas de DNS, pues una URL _se resuelve_ a una IP, pero no al revés. Considero que es importante tratar de usar la terminología correcta, o al menos no asumir el significado de los términos y explicarlos con otras palabras, para evitar confusiones.

Comment: Sucede algo similar con el término _redirección_, que tiene un significado específico. Si lo que ocurre es realmente una redirección y no sabes de dónde nace, inspecciona primero los resultados que obtiene el cliente, para ver qué tipo de redirección está ocurriendo. 

Es un Status HTTP? Es un Header? Es una redirección vía javascript? Una vez que sepas cómo está operando esa redirección (nadie puede saberlo de antemano), entonces

Comment: @jachguate  por ejemplo tengo la IP 128.199.100.xx  si ingreso con esta IP me redirecciona a mi dominio https://yourdomain.com   y  no deseo que esta acción suceda

Comment: ¿Si _ingresas_ con esa IP a dónde? No es lo mismo hacer una petición HTTP/S, que _ingresar_ al servidor, por ejemplo, vía SSH o Telnet. Esto cada vez resulta más confuso.

Comment: @jachguate si ingresas  por medio de una petición HTTP: http://128.199.100.xx  redirecciona a https://yourdomain.com